# Obtener multiple informacion seguida de una coma de una misma columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero agrupar la información por teléfono obteniendo una columna que tenga todos los nombres de "MLS_Agent_Name" cuyo telefono coincida seguidos de una coma.
Ademas, como podria agregar esta nueva info a una nueva tabla.
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score -1):

Buenas Amigo te sugiero que agregues mas detalles o algunos ejemplos para entenderlo mejor, pero por lo que entiendo es que quieres una columna con los datos de 2 columnas separas por una coma. Para juntar 2 campos puedes usar la función `CONCAT()` donde especificas todo lo que contenga tu cadena.

Ejemplo

```
SELECT CONCAT(MLS_Agent_Name,',',MLS_Agent_Phone) from Tabla;
```

y para agregar los datos de una consulta puedes usar la función `INSERT INTO SELECT`
desconozco los datos de tu segunda tabla, pero esto lo que haces es agregar todos los datos de tu tabla a otra y puedes añadir el `CONCAT()` como valor para una columna de tu segunda tabla.

Esta seria la sintaxis

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
```

En caso de que quieras almacenar esa consulta también puedes usar las `Views` o Vistas.

Comment: Esta respuesta no agrupa todos los `MLS_Agent_Name` con el mismo teléfono, sino simplemente la unión de dos campos separados por una coma